# Assign specific initial parameters from random values, among a pool of parameters

Tags: c#

I am using a function to initialize values for a constructor.
In the constructor I call this function, and initialize parameters based on the specific type passed in the constructor.

```
public class myclass()
{
    // class parameters of type int\

    public myclass()
    {
        GenerateValues(1);
    }

    private void GenerateValues( int type_of_worker)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        //generate random values for the params
    }

}
```

With this I can generate random values based on the type of worker passed to the constructor, so I can have a basic worker, a technician, a director, a manager and so on.

Each role has requirements though, so when I create the worker of type "manager", it has to have at least 2 parameters that are above 50 (min 0 max 99). If is a director, it needs 3 parameters equal or above 75.

How can I tell C# to create random values for X parameters, but if the type is manager, 2 of them has to be above 50, or if it is a director, 3 parameters ahs to be above 75?

For example, if I create a manager, I would use this in GenerateValues:

```
// main parameters - any value between 1-99 is fine
par1 = rnd.Next(1.99);
par2 = rnd.Next(1.99);
par3 = rnd.Next(1.99);
par4 = rnd.Next(1.99);
par5 = rnd.Next(1.99);
//extra parameters - ANY 2 of these above 50 for manager
par6 = rnd.Next(1.99);
par7 = rnd.Next(50.99);
par8 = rnd.Next(50.99);
par9 = rnd.Next(1.99);
```

The problem here is that I don't want to specify which of the extra parameters is between 50 and 99; but would like that any 2 of the extra parameters has to be between 50 and 99.

I could assign values and then read them, changing them again, but it is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in more OOP way, since it's C#. See implementation below.

1. First I define an interface to define a contract. From each worker type we should get integer parameters. Not sure how your parameters look like, I used just an array of integers.
2. Then I add abstract class to share a code for generating N random numbers from given interval.
3. Then I just create concrete types implementing only specific logic.

For simplicity I used LINQ helper functions.
The following rules are applied to get set of random numbers:

- Technician - 2 values from interval [0, 99] and 5 values from [0, 50]. Notice int Next function min parameter is inclusive whereas max parameter is exclusive.
- Director - 2 values from interval [50, 99] and 5 values from [0, 50].
- Manager - 3 values from interval [75, 99] and 5 values from [0, 50].

  ```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public interface IWorker {
      int[] GetParameters();
  }

  abstract class Worker : IWorker {

      public abstract int[] GetParameters();

      protected IEnumerable<int> GenerateNValues(int quanity, int min, int max) {
          var theRandom = new Random();
          var theResult = new List<int>(quanity);
          for (int i = 0; i < quanity; i++)
              theResult.Add(theRandom.Next(min, max));
          return theResult;
      }

      protected IEnumerable<int> Shuffle(IEnumerable<int> array) {
          var theRandom = new Random();
          return array.OrderBy(x => theRandom.Next()).ToArray();  
      }
  }

  class Technician : Worker {
      public override int[] GetParameters() {
          return GenerateNValues(2, 0, 100).Concat(GenerateNValues(5, 10, 51)).ToArray();
      }
  }

  class Director : Worker {
      public override int[] GetParameters() {
          return GenerateNValues(2, 50, 100).Concat(GenerateNValues(5, 10, 51)).ToArray();
      }
  }

  class Manager : Worker {
      public override int[] GetParameters() {
          return Shuffle(GenerateNValues(3, 75, 100).Concat(GenerateNValues(5, 10, 51))).ToArray();
      }
  }


  public class MyClass
  {
      public MyClass(IWorker aWorker)
      {
          var theParameters = aWorker.GetParameters();
          // do stuff with parameters
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I didn't think to use interfaces, since I always thought that they are useful when you have different classes in different files, and you need consistency in how they work. The data that I have is mostly int type, your assumption is sound. I didn't try this yet, but would this approach allow me to have for example 2 parameters for the manager, above 50, among a pool of X parameters? Because most of my issues are related to the logic to accomplish that, without me specifying which field has to be above 50. I just pass a list, and 2 out of X parameters, has to be above 50.

Comment: @newbiez This is OOP way of reusing code, of course you can just focus on `GenerateNValues ` function, make it global static and use it directly when you apply your generation rules. So yes, as I described above this approach should let you define specific logic for each worker type - for each case you define rules what will be generated: like 2 items [50, 99] + 5 items [0, 50]. The only thing now values are grouped by rules and if you want random order then you should shuffle array before returning it from `GenerateNValues`.

Comment: I also added `Shuffle` function and use it in Manager class. So after generating groups of random numbers, all of the numbers are shuffled before return.